# Spring websockets with minimum dependencies without any annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-websocket

I am looking for an example of how to do Spring Websockets without any annotations and with the minimum amount of dependencies. I am looking for a pure java client side example if that is possible?

Also would like to know if spring-boot-starter-parent dependency is necessary for the running Websockets in Spring.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Spring boot starter is only necessary if you are writing spring boot application. Have a look at the examples [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html).